# Error when importing an unmanaged solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I'm trying to migrate some customizations from our development environment to the test environment. I have everything I need in a solution. When I import this into the test environment, it fails with the error;

***An item with the same key has already been added.***

In the error file that I download from the solution import screen, it's listed against the Form ItemType for the Incident entity. My solution contains a new custom form, it also has the definitions for the 2 default "Information" forms.

With verbose tracing, I can see the error in an xml string;

```xml
<formXml LocalizedName="Case" OriginalName="Case"
         Description="Service request case associated with a contract."
         id="Incident" processed="true">
    <result result="failure" errorcode="0x80044150"
            errortext="An item with the same key has already been added."
            datetime="09:52:28.65" datetimeticks="635049859486557248" />
</formXml>
```

this is within the entitySubhandlers node. However there's nothing to pinpoint exactly what the issue is. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: have you got any Lookup field on newly created form?

Comment: In past I got this error from a plugin which were because if `entity.Attributes.Add`. But for you its happening while importing the solution!

Comment: I have quite a few Lookup fields on the form. Some are lookup to OOTB entities such as customer, others are lookup's to custom entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get around this. I documented my customisations, did a restore of our test environment (which is itself a restore of production) as a new development environment. Once I did this, everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem today and found a solution.

In CRM you have the display name, name and physical (database column) name. For some reason the physical name is sometimes generate with capitals and sometimes not.

My scenario:
contact with field "Field 1"
(display - name - physical)
Dev environment: "Field 1" "new_field1" "new_Field1"
Test environment: "Field 1" "newfield1" "new_field1" => note that there is no capital F here

The occured when I deleted the field on dev and recreated it. Previously the physicial name was "new_Field1" on dev, now it is "new_field1".

A suggested solution I found on the web is deleting the field and recreating it. That would obviously not work for me but it might work for you. See: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmpowerobjects/archive/2013/07/01/field-is-not-unique-error-when-importing-a-solution-in-crm-2011.aspx

My solution was to update the field directly in the database (you cannot do this if you have a CRM online environment, I'm using CRM 2011 on-premise Rollup 15, SQL server 2008 R2 SP1). 
You need to modify the table schema + the physical name of the record in the Metadataschema.Attributes. Do this at your own risk as this is not supported by MS and take a full backup.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error while importing customisation to the Dev environment:
*An item with the same key has already been added* on User entity.

I saw James Wood's answer and compared the User entities on boths side. And realised that I had 3 custom fields on both sides. These were created by a 3rd party solution separately on the live and Dev.

I just deleted the 3 custom fields in Dev environment. When I tried the import again, it worked perfectly.

Thanks James for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and it was caused by changing the **type** of an existing field.

The current system had a field called `ecs_salutation` of type **Single Line of Text**. The solution had deleted and readded this field as an **Option Set**

The import would fail because the field types didnt match. I had to manually remove the field from the forms, delete it from the entity and republish before being able to import the solution succesfully

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can occur when, you have a field in both environments (with the same schema name) but they are of different types.

Have you already customised the test environment? If so I would look to compare the custom fields on that entity.

Comment: Thanks. I've been through all the custom fields and any that already exist on the test environment have the same type as those on the development environment.

Comment: Yes the test environment is customised. I've visually inspected the fields and can't see any differences. Is there any quick way to check, some sort of comparison tool?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered into this problem today when importing customization from dev into production. Turned out there is a custom field that was deleted in dev and then re-created using the same schema name, but different data type. I deleted that field in production and the customization import is successful.